# Recommendation for propensity score analysis text?

Tags: references, propensity-scores

I'm considering purchasing a propensity score analysis text and welcome recommendations.

I know the basics of propensity score analysis but would like an up to date reference guide & don't mind more technical texts.

Guo and Fraser's *Propensity Score Analysis: Statistical Methods and Applications (Advanced Quantitative Techniques in the Social Sciences) 2nd Edition* and Pan and Bai's *Propensity Score Analysis: Fundamentals and Developments 1st Edition* both receive high marks on amazon.

Any preferences from those who have conducted PSA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imbens and Rubin is a very good starting point.

Imbens, G., & Rubin, D. (2015). Causal Inference for Statistics, Social, and Biomedical Sciences: An Introduction. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781139025751